# How to capture Sybase RAISERROR in Mybatis-Spring?

Tags: spring, sybase, mybatis, raiserror

I am trying to capture error messages in my Java code from stored procedures in Sybase using `RAISERROR`, but nothing is being caught, even though when I call the proc directly I can see the error is thrown.

I understand that Mybatis-Spring

> translates MyBatis exceptions into Spring DataAccessException

So I have coded my Mapper class thusly:

```
void insertData(Data toInsert) throws Exception, DataAccessException;
```

I'm trying to catch both of these exceptions, but nothing is caught.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

```
try {
    myMapper.insertData(data);
}
catch (org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException e) {
    Throwable ee = use.getCause();
    // getMessage on chained exception gets message from RAISERROR
    log.error(ee.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Cheers,
Stephen